# They did not contact my sponsor?

Tags: visas, uk, application-status

I got an email from from the UK embassy in Abu Dhabi, saying your visa application has been concluded.

But they did not contact my sponsor. Does this mean they did not grant my visa but refused it?

Comment: They wouldn't normally contact anybody when assessing your application - they don't have time. Instead, they go off the evidence you give them, plus what comes up for their databases. If you relied on them contacting your sponsor, then you made an error.

Comment: okay thanks, and do i expect tomorrow my passport will return or after tomorrow? if i received this email on 23 june yesterday

Comment: We don’t have any way to know how long the return of your passport will take

Answer (score 3):

Answer given in the comments:

> They wouldn't normally contact anybody when assessing your application - they don't have time. Instead, they go off the evidence you give them, plus what comes up for their databases. If you relied on them contacting your sponsor, then you made an error.

Just because they didn't contact your sponsor doesn't mean your visa is refused.

Answer (score 1):

You should have your decision by now, indeed a few years ago.

But for others in the same situation, getting mails or letters about your visa before you can get your passport does not indicate anything about getting your visa or not.

In case of sponsors, as this question asks about, you should have send in information about their financial situation and the officer looking at your case should have enough information to judge whether your sponsor can be relied upon to bear the cost of the travel.
Your sending contact information for the sponsor does allow contacting them and they will check out a percentage of cases where contact information is available, but that might be a very small percentage (and I doubt they publish it anyhow.)

As indicated in a comment to this answer, by @Traveller, they can contact the sponsor in the landing interview.

So when waiting for a decision about a visa you applied for be patient as the visa or your passport without it will come when it is time.

Comment: FWIW I’ve sponsored a UK visit visa twice and had no pre-decision contact. The 2nd time however when my visitor arrived in the UK a Border Officer called me as part of the landing interview

Comment: @Traveller that's good to know.  I often advise people who are worried about landing interviews to have the person they're visiting near the phone.  It's nice to know that this can actually be useful :-)  Willeke, I would also note that these "passport is ready" messages are typically crafted so as to avoid telegraphing any information about the result -- otherwise they might as be "application was refused" or "application was successful" messages.

Comment: @phoog I was actually at the airport. If things had gone awry during the landing interview I don’t know if my physical presence would have been of any use to rescue the situation but I would always recommend going to meet a visitor, particularly if said visitor’s application relies entirely on having a sponsor. It also follows that a sponsor should be knowledgeable about the details given in the application, in case they are asked about them.